# Is there a name for a pattern which alternates circle and square tiles?

Tags: terminology

[image]

Google search doesn't give any results or [it does](https://www.houseplanshelper.com/tile-patterns-gallery.html) but for a different pattern type :

[image]

Answer (score 1):

[Checker board with checkers.](https://www.alamy.com/stock-photo-checker-beard-with-checkers-104493085.html) (It does not appear to be a pattern with an official name.)

Comment: "check" is a mix of "chess" and "checkers"?

Comment: Thanks @virolino, correcting my bazaar spelling now...